# php artisan serve parse error

Tags: php, laravel-5

i know this question already exist, but i could not solve via the other responses, so the first time i runed **php artisan serve** it worked, i changed the routes so the logic go to the controllers and they can call the views, so i have this at the moment.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/',PagesController@home);
Route::get('about',PagesController@about);
```

**PagesController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
   public function home(){
       $People = array("Joao","Miguel","Carlos");
       return view('welcome',compact('People'));
   }

   public function about(){
       return view ("pages.about");
   }
}
```

when i changed the routes i turned off the connection via local server on my cmd, after that i tryed again the command **php artisan serve** and now i get a **parse error** like this:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ',' or ')'

**routes before**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
$People = array("Joao","Miguel","Carlos");
return view('welcome',compact('People'));
});

Route::get('/about',function(){
    return view ("pages.about");
});
```

Have no idea why this happens :S if someone can give me a tipe i appreciate :)

Comment: When you compare the routes before and after your change, you should see the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
Route::get('about',PagesController@about);
                                  ^--
```

there's no quotes, so that's `<undefinedconstant>@<undefinedconstant>`

`@` is the error suppression operator in PHP, and cannot appear "inside" a variable/constant name.

Comment: what a shame, just so easy, im starting learning laravel thaught was something harder that stoped me :/